# sort currency datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to sort a column with datatables plugin.

The column contains:

```
10 €
20 €
200 €
1000 €
200 €
200.20 €
10.30 €
```

the problem is not ordered correctly and take it as a string.
I am using this code but does not work:

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "formatted-num-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },

    "formatted-num-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },

    "formatted-num-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );
```

greetings and thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but it's better to split currency and price columns.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to link the column to your plug-in type in your call to `dataTable` (after declaring it). For example, if it is your third column (hence the two `null`s) do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table-id').dataTable({
        "aoColumns": [
            null,
            null,
            { "sType": "formatted-num" }
        ]
    });
} );
```

Alternatively you can use a [type detection plug-in](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/type-detection) to automatically work out the type of each column